# MVC radio buttons for 3 bool properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have a model with 3 bool properties:

```
public class ViewModel {
  public bool A { get; set; }
  public bool B { get; set; }
  public bool C { get; set; }
}
```

If I'm right they are all `false` by default.
I want to have 3 radio buttons, so only one of them can be `true`:

```
<input asp-for="A" name="type" type="radio" value="true" id="A"/>
<input asp-for="B" name="type" type="radio" value="true" id="B"/>
<input asp-for="C" name="type" type="radio" value="true" id="C"/>
```

But when I choose one out of the 3 and submit my form, every value in the view model will be `false`.

How can I solve this? The main thing is that I only want to use 3 radio buttons.

Comment: You are only showing us the declaration of the properties and their HTML counterpart not how you get the values. If you are expecting "true" but get false you are not getting the values from the input elements but rather their default values from the properties which is always "false" for booleans unless they are declared otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio button works in a different way than check box. In case of radio button the value of the selected radio button from a group of radio buttons will be sent back to the action.

To group radio buttons - the `name` property of the html elements has to be the same (which I can see in your html). Now all you need is to have a variable to catch the `value` of the selected radio button. You have to set the `value` property for the radio buttons.

**Html:**

```
<input asp-for="A" name="type" type="radio" value="A" id="A"/>
<input asp-for="B" name="type" type="radio" value="B" id="B"/>
<input asp-for="C" name="type" type="radio" value="C" id="C"/>
```

**Then in the action:**

```
public class ViewModel {
  public string type { get; set; }
}
```

The value of the `type` property will be available in the `type` variable on the server side. e.g. "A " or "B" or "C" but not True/False.